# Laravel 5.4 where in statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

I have the following query:

```
 $items = DB::table('item')->select('*')->whereIn('id', $it)->get();
```

in this case $it is an array of five integers, if I do dd($it) I get this:

```
array:5 [ 0 => "56"  1 => "57"  2 => "58"  3 => "59"  4 => "60"]
```

My issue is that $items is only returning the data for the first and last id (56 and 60), I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, and I'm getting no errors either.
I also tried it like this (and I know about SQL-injection) to see the results, but it's the same

```
 $items = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT * FROM item WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$it).")"));
```

Hope I made myself clear, my english is not very good,
thanks

Comment: Is the array $it dynamically generated ?

Comment: I have a previous query to get the id's and then I passed them to $it by doing this:

´foreach ($itemorden as $value) {
        echo  $it[] = $value->id_item;
    }´

Comment: so maybe the last ids 56 and 60 are not added when the array is created, I will suggest you get a fixed array for testing sake with those last values to really verify

Comment: and also dont forget to cast the ids to ints if they are strings thats if they have "" or ' around them

Comment: Using a fixed array I get the same results :(
Only first and last id are considered, no idea why

Comment: I've stuck in this for hours, you know what may be causing it? @razzbee

Comment: Well I cant tell why it is causing that but am sure there should be a typo somewhere,your code too is correct